# Changing AUCTeX viewer results in errors claiming TeX-engine is wrongly set, although it is set correctly

Tags: auctex

This question was completely rewritten, see the [previous version](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/revisions/21647/5).

---

I have this XeLaTeX file:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}  

äätewää--llll
\end{document}
```

which produces the (intended) image when compiled with `C-c C-a`:

[image: result]

my `init.el` used for that is:

```lisp
(require 'package)
(dolist (source '(("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                  ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
                  ))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives source t))
(package-initialize)
(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))
(defvar tmtxt/packages
  '( auctex))
(dolist (p tmtxt/packages)
  (when (not (package-installed-p p))
    (package-install p)))

(setq-default TeX-engine 'xetex)
(setq-default TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

**all the above is expected so far**

---

However, if i change my `init.el` to use a different viewer (latex-preview-pane-mode):

```lisp
(require 'package)
(dolist (source '(("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                  ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
                  ))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives source t))
(package-initialize)
(when (not package-archive-contents)
  (package-refresh-contents))
(defvar tmtxt/packages
  '( auctex))
(dolist (p tmtxt/packages)
  (when (not (package-installed-p p))
    (package-install p)))

(setq-default TeX-engine 'xetex)
(setq-default TeX-PDF-mode t)

(custom-set-variables
 '(TeX-view-program-list
   (quote (("preview-pane-mode" latex-preview-pane-mode))))

 '(TeX-view-program-selection
   (quote
    (((output-dvi has-no-display-manager)
      "dvi2tty")
     ((output-dvi style-pstricks)
      "dvips and gv")
     (output-dvi "xdvi")
     (engine-omega "Atril")
     (output-pdf "preview-pane-mode")
     (output-html "xdg-open"))))
)
```

i receive with the same XeLaTeX source as above the following error:

```
!...............................................  
! For immediate help type H <return>.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
! 
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: What command have you bound to `C-c a`? That key combination is not bound in standard auctex – it is reserved for private keybindings. (Same with `C-c` followed by any letter.) Also, do check that the variable is really set as you wanted it to. Use `C-h v` for this.

Comment: Ah, sry. I confused the keybinding, I meant `C-c C-a` (TeX-command-run-all). But i don't know where I have that keybinding from (I didn't define it in my init.el), I've read that probably on the internet somewhere. The variable `TeX-engine` is set when I open a tex file.

Comment: Additionally: I've made a small but important error in my tex source code - However the given error message is still correct.

Comment: Ah, the `C-c C-a` keybinding is standard with auctex. I am not sure what you are saying about `TeX-engine`. Can you check its value *after* opening the TeX file, *in* the TeX file's buffer? Just in case some hook goes and changes it buffer-locally or something.

Comment: Does it work, if you add the line `%%% TeX-engine: xetex` in the file itself?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I did check exactly that. `C-h v` says, the value `TeX-engine` is set to `xetex`.

Comment: @user93559 no, that doesn't change anything. I receive still the same error message.

Comment: What does `M-: (TeX-command-expand "%(latex)" (TeX-master-file)) RET` return for you in the LaTeX buffer?  Does it change anything if you issue `C-c C-c` instead of `C-c C-a`?

Comment: @giordano your command outputs `"xelatex"`. `C-c C-c` doesn't change anything.

Comment: `C-c C-c` executes the command returned by the expansion of `%(latex)`.  I really can't understand what's the problem.  You should provide a full recipe to reproduce your problem starting from `emacs -Q`, otherwise it'll very difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: Does running `xetex yourfile.tex` in a shell work?

Comment: @JeanPierre `xetex yourfile.tex` works not (which is expected, XeTeX != XeLaTeX; I'm using the latter here). XeLaTeX yourfile.tex works.  **@all** Additionally, I have completly rewritten my question

Comment: @toogley  Sorry, I still can't reproduce it even with your new instructions.  You can guess that setting the viewer shouldn't affect at all the selection of the engine.